# Push messages do not come when on 3G?

Tags: android, push-notification, 3g

I implemented push notification system and I noticed that push messages do not ever come when I am on 3G or 4G (mobile Internet).

When I connect to wifi, they come regularly.

Is this behavior bound to Android OS or we can write a code to change it?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you "implemented push notification system"? Do you mean you added GCM support, or something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare I implemented Parse.com 3rd party library. Regardless of myself, I noticed that push messages from other apps do not come unless I am connected to wifi. I am not sure if this is Android OS limitation or it's something limited to my mobile phone or my 3G provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I implemented Parse.com 3rd party library. Regardless of myself, I noticed that push messages from other apps do not come unless I am connected to wifi.

If you see the same behavior with stuff from Google (Gmail, Google Play app updates, etc.), then the problem lies with your phone or carrier. If the Google stuff works (they use what amounts to GCM), then your problem lies with Parse.com and whatever the other apps are using for push.

GCM (and the C2DM precursor) work over mobile data or WiFi. It is a bit tricky to implement a push system as a third-party library, which is why I recommend firmware solutions (GCM, Amazon's just-announced Kindle Fire equivalent, etc.). In particular, maintaining a mobile data connection to the push server, with enough heartbeats to keep the connection alive without really draining the battery, is difficult to get right, particularly given subtle mobile carrier or device variations. Google has more experience with this than do most firms, and Amazon only has to worry about a handful of Kindle Fire models.

Comment: Yes, Gmail comes, but neither facebook nor any other push messages arrive when I am on 3G. Do you have any material to recommend? It's not a big issue now when I see that I am not alone, but you gave me an itch :).

Comment: @sandalone: "Do you have any material to recommend?" -- to recommend about what? You can read about GCM in [the developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and in finer books on Android application development. :-)

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not realize you were exclusive to GCM.

Comment: @sandalone: I'm not, but I am having to guess what you mean by "Do you have any material to recommend?".

Comment: You said `It is a bit tricky to implement a push system as a third-party library, which is why I recommend firmware solutions ... In particular, maintaining a mobile data connection to the push server, with enough heartbeats to keep the connection alive without really draining the battery, is difficult to get right, ... Google has more experience with this than do most firms`. I thought you may have docs on these advanced topics?

Comment: @sandalone: Ah, that. My primary source is a 2010 Google I|O conference presentation on C2DM, where they opened the kimono a bit on the implementation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLM4LajwDVc I seem to recall some related material was in the 2012 Google I|O presentation on GCM: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoaP6hcDctM